# How to join two long queries from one table?

Tags: mysql, join

I have columns

```
First name | last name | nr (individual number) | pref1 (preference1) | pref2 (preference2)| pref3(preference3) | situation | distance | sex
```

with 100 records in one table ap

In the results of all I can't have redundancies. It means when in first group of result I get individual number (column "nr") of fore example '2112' it can't be displayed in last one of results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT nr FROM ap
```

Records from first query:

```
WHERE sex='F' and pref1='1' ORDER BY situation DESC, distance DESC
AND  WHERE (sex='F' and pref2='1' and situation= ' ' ) ORDER BY distance DESC
and WHERE (sex='F' and pref3='1' and situation= ' ' ) ORDER BY distance DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Then I would like to join results from second query:

```
WHERE sex='M' and pref1='2' ORDER BY situation DESC, distance DESC
AND WHERE (sex='M' and pref2='2' and situation= ' ' ) ORDER BY distance DESC
AND WHERE (sex='M' and pref3='2' and situation= ' ' ) ORDER BY distance DESC
LIMIT 7
```

and then join to all records from last query:

```
WHERE sex='F' and pref1='3' ORDER BY situation DESC, distance DESC
AND WHERE (sex='F' and pref2='3' and situation= ' ' ) ORDER BY distance DESC
AND WHERE (sex='F' and pref3='3' and situation= ' ' ) ORDER BY distance DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Since the SQL you are demonstrating is not valid, it is quite unclear what you are after. Can you please show some sample table rows and  a sample of what your query output would be?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [UNION](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0040__Select-Query/UNIONJoins.htm), It is just a simple example using UNION

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT nr FROM  
(select distinct nr from ap WHERE sex='F' and pref1='1' ORDER BY situation DESC,   distance DESC Union
select distinct nr from ap WHERE (sex='F' and pref2='1' and situation= ' ' ) ORDER BY distance DESC union
select distinct nr from ap WHERE (sex='F' and pref3='1' and situation= ' ' ) ORDER BY distance DESC union
LIMIT 4)
UNION
(select distinct nr from ap WHERE sex='M' and pref1='2' ORDER BY situation DESC,   distance DESC union
select distinct nr from ap WHERE (sex='M' and pref2='2' and situation= ' ' ) ORDER BY distance DESC union
select distinct nr from ap WHERE (sex='M' and pref3='2' and situation= ' ' ) ORDER BY distance DESC union
LIMIT 7
)
UNION
(select distinct nr from ap WHERE sex='F' and pref1='3' ORDER BY situation DESC,   distance DESC union
select distinct nr from ap WHERE (sex='F' and pref2='3' and situation= ' ' ) ORDER BY distance DESC union
select distinct nr from ap WHERE (sex='F' and pref3='3' and situation= ' ' ) ORDER BY distance DESC union
LIMIT 10
))
```

Comment: The relational calculus does not ensure that, but probably in MYSQL/ORACLE what you said is right.

Comment: This isn't anything like valid SQL. Multiple `WHERE` and multiple `ORDER BY` per union group? Not going to work...

Comment: It doesn't work with SQL :( Any others ideas? I have been trying to do it since yesterday